# How to avoid cyclic dependency in UI application

Tags: design, object-oriented, c++, programming-practices, object-oriented-design

I'm developing an UI application where I ran into an issue with a cyclic dependency. Here is the simplified code, to explain the problem.

```
#include <list>

class UiStyle;
UiStyle* CreateStyle();

class UiWindow {
public:
    virtual void Draw() = 0;
};

class UiMenu : public UiWindow {
public:
    void Draw() override {
        // Some UI drawing

        // How should I implement changing style from here?
    }
};

class UiApplication {
public:
    void Draw() {
        for (UiWindow* window : this->windows)
            window->Draw();
    }

protected:
    void SetStyle(UiStyle *style);

    void AddWindow(UiWindow* window) {
        this->windows.push_back(window);
    }

private:
    std::list<UiWindow*> windows;
};

class UiMainApplication : public UiApplication {
public:
    void Initialize() {
        this->SetStyle(CreateStyle());

        this->AddWindow(new UiMenu());
    }
};
```

Explanation:

- **UiStyle** - application style class.
- **CreateStyle** - method that creates some UI style.
- **UiWindow** - interface of an UI window (not to be changed)
- **UiMenu** - some implemented UI window from where I need to change a style.
- **UiApplication** - base application class that provides managing windows, styles, etc. (not to be changed)
- **UiMainApplication** - implemented application that adds real windows, sets real style.

The problem I face is about changing the application style from inside `UiMenu`. How can `UiMenu` call `UiApplication::SetStyle`?

Of course, I could pass `UiMainApplication` pointer to `UiMenu`, then create public method `UiMainApplication::SetStyle` that will allow to call `UiApplication::SetStyle`, and call `UiMainApplication::SetStyle` from `UiMenu`.  But, as far as I know, it's bad practice, to have a bidirectional reference, like A -> B and B -> A. In my case, `UiMainApplication` would refer to `UiMenu` and `UiMenu` refer to `UiMenuApplication`.

Hence I think it's not the best way to implement it.

Hope for your help! I will be glad to any suggestions!

Comment: It is not entirely clear what your problem is. Are you asking how to draw the menu item in the style currently set for the application? Or do you want to change the style of the application from the menu item?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: To me, it looks very clear it is the second of your two interpretations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cyclic references sometimes have their place, and before rejecting them as a solution, I think it is important to understand why and when they may become an issue, and if this issue really applies to your case.

For example, as you mentioned by yourself, one could solve this problem by introducing an ctor parameter `UiMainApplication *` to `UiMenu`. I would implement it this way:

```
class UIMenu
{
   UiMainApplication *_app;
public:
     UIMenu(UiMainApplication * app){
         _app=app;
     }
     void Draw() override {
          if(_app) {
              _app->SetStyle(...);
          }
          //...
    }
};
```

This would result in a cyclic dependency between `UiMainApplication` and `UiMenu` However, this is only a compile time dependency. At run time, you still can instantiate an `UiMainApplication` object without creating an `UiMenu` object first. It is also possible to create an `UiMenu` object without `UiMainApplication`, by passing a `nullptr` as parameter, if you need one for testing purposes.

You need to decide if this compile time dependency is acceptable for your case. It will forbid to place `UiMenu` in a reusable library module independend from `UiMainApplication`, but if you don't intend to do so, this may be perfectly fine.

Of course, it is possible to get rid of the compile time dependency, if necessary.  For this, one can create a abstract new class `SetStyleService` with a virtual method `SetStyle`. This class definition can be part of the same library module where `UiMenu` is placed, or in a separate "interface" library. Then instead of expecting a pointer to `UiMainApplication` in the  `UiMenu` ctor, you make it expecting a pointer to `SetStyleService`. `UiMainApplication` will have to be derived from `SetStyleService` and implement `SetStyle` accordingly.  (Note the same behaviour can be accomplished by using function pointers and passing a pointer to `SetStyle` into `UiMenu`).

I would probably stick to the first approach as long as there is no real need for the second. Just because someone has written somewhere *"bidrectional dependencies are bad practice"* I would not follow such a recommendation thoughtlessly, but first check if the potential drawbacks of such a dependency really applies to my specific case.

Comment: In C++ specifically, though, every pointer cycle needs to be thought about in terms of ownership: who's responsible for deleting resources, how to present use-after-free, etc.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: that is IMHO pretty trivial in this case: `UiMainApplication` is owning all window pointers like `UiMenu`, and `UiMenu` gets a pointer to `UiMainApplication *` ,  which has a lifetime longer that itself. `UiMainApplication` should definitely not try to use any window pointer after the latter was freed.